# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ||T^n||$ where $T$ is left-shift operator on $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be the left-shift operator on $l^2$. I want to calculate the two limits $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|T^nx\|_2\;\text{and}\; \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|T^n\|$

I have no problems with the first one $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|T^nx\|_2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \left(\sum_{i=n}^\infty|x_i|^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2} = 0.$$

But I'm not sure about the second one. I tried to write it out as $$ \|T^n\|= \inf\{c>0: \forall x_i \; \|T^nx\|_2 \leq c\|x\|_2\} $$

but I can't find a proper $c$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|T^{n}x\|\leq \|x\|$, so  $\|T^{n}\| \leq 1$. Also $T^{n}(e_{n+1})=e_{1}$ Hence $\|T^{n}\| \geq 1$. So $\|T^{n}\| = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Isn't LEFT SHIFT means that $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=T(x_2,\ldots)$ (so, $Te_1=0$)? BTW If this is the case, just take into account that $T^ne_{n+1}=e_1$.

Comment: I had taken $T$ to be the right shift. I have corrected the answer. @TitoEliatron

Comment: I prefer to say "forward" or "backward" shift to avoid confusion.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your help. However, I can't see how $T^n(e_{n+1}) = e_1$ implies *greater* or equal. As far as I can tell, $T^n(e_{n+1}) = e_1$ implies $||T^n|| = 1$ by it self (not >). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @aaa Suppose $\|T^{n}x\| \leq c \|x\|$ for all $x$. Put $x=e_{n+1}$. You get $1\leq c$. So $\|T^{n}\|$ is the infimum of  a set of numbers each of which is $\geq 1$. Hence $\|T^{n}\| \geq 1$.